# Target specific element if it contains another element only with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML setups and I'm trying to target the `class="chosen-with-children"` with CSS2 or CSS3 only if the `div` also contains the `class="children"`. Any idea how to solve this? I hope this is possible.

Thanks in advance.

**1.**

```
<div class="wcapf-layered-nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="chosen-with-children">
            <a class="" href=""></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**2.**

```
<div class="wcapf-layered-nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="chosen-with-children">
            <a class="" href=""></a>

            <ul class="children">
                <li class="chosen">
                    <a class="" href=""></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Not possible with pure CSS, you would have to use JavaScript. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible using pure CSS, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector).

If you wanted to use jQuery you could do this:

```js
$(".chosen-with-children").each(function() {
  if($("ul", this).hasClass("children")) {
    $(this).addClass("has-child-class");
  }
})
```

```css
.chosen-with-children.has-child-class > a {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wcapf-layered-nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="chosen-with-children">
      <a class="" href="">Link 1</a>

      <ul class="children">
        <li class="chosen">
          <a class="" href="">Link 1a</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="chosen-with-children">
      <a class="" href="">Link 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```